# getting exception while using media player

Tags: android

I am using media player to play a mp3 file.But when i run it,i am getting the null pointer exception.Please tell me what is the problem.

This is the code:

```
package com.example.soundplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * Variables
     */
    MediaPlayer mp = null;
    String hello = "Hello!";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         * Talking with the buttonHello
         */
        final Button buttonHello = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idHello);
        buttonHello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                managerOfSound(hello);
            } // END onClick()
        }); // END buttonHello
    } // END onCreate()

    /**
     * Manager of Sounds
     */
    protected void managerOfSound(String theText) {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
        }
        if (theText == hello){
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
            mp.start();}
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
08-22 13:13:01.001: W/dalvikvm(785): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-22 13:13:01.001: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.example.soundplayer.MainActivity.managerOfSound(MainActivity.java:57)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.example.soundplayer.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-22 13:13:01.020: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting exception in this line:

```
 mp.start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the result from create method and check that result before using that mediaPlayer because create function will return media player object if successfully created and NULL if it fail to create media player.

[check the description of that function in official site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

**`a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed`**

One more thing You need not to call prepare() function because  `On successfully created MediaPlayer , prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.`

you can check mp is null or not before calling mp.start

```
if(mp!=null)
  mp.start();
```

Comment: How to do that sir?Can you please give me few lines of code to understand this.

Comment: Also look at this description http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#preparingasync

Answer (score 1):

According to the MediaPlayer state diagram, you have to call `mp.prepare()` before `mp.start()`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
if(mp!=null) {
   mp.start();
}
```

Comment: still showing the same problem sir.Now the exception is in this line: mp.prepare();

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the problem but you should change this:

```
if (theText.equals(" hello"){
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();}
```

Comment: Sorry sir,but the problem is still the same.

Comment: By the way do you have the file sound.mp3 in your raw folder?

Comment: Okay try my edited answer. Comment out mp = new MediaPlayer();